# Java Оптимизация кода

Tags: java, оптимизация, java-8

Нужно оптимизировать этот код для олимпиады, т.к. превышен лимит времени выполнения. (лимит - 3s, пишет, что выполняется за ~3.050 s

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {
        
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        final Stream<String> x = Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt")); 
        final int num = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
        int lines = -1;
        int[] connections = new int[num];
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {lines++;}
        for (int a = 1; a < lines; a++) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(x.skip(a).findFirst().get());
            
            connections[Integer.parseInt(scan.next())]++;
            connections[Integer.parseInt(scan.next())]++;
        }
        int first = 0,second = 0;
        for (int t : connections) { 
            if (t > first) {
                second = first;
                first = t;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(first + " " + second);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Оптимизируйте вот это `x.skip(a).findFirst().get()`. А вообще вы, зная задачу, не смогли собрать оптимальное решение - как мы должны дать вам оптимальное решение без знания вашей задачи?

Comment: также обратите внимание, сколько раз вы читаете входной файл.

Comment: у вас она не может выполнятся, потому как у вас здесь бесконечный цикл while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {lines++;} - нет вызова scanner.next(); и курсор не переходит на следующую строку, посему всегда остается на первой и возвращает true при вызове scanner.hasNextLine(). добавьте задание , а в идеале еще и исходный файл.

Comment: Можете посчитать кол-во линий в файле так: `x.count()`. Не обязательно создавать отдальный сканер и итерировать по файлу. Вы же уже прочитали все линии в `Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt")); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить это:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {lines++;}
    for (int a = 1; a < lines; a++) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(x.skip(a).findFirst().get());
        
        connections[Integer.parseInt(scan.next())]++;
        connections[Integer.parseInt(scan.next())]++;
    }
```

на код ниже:

```
int lines = 1;
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(x.skip(lines).findFirst().get());
        
    connections[Integer.parseInt(scan.next())]++;
    connections[Integer.parseInt(scan.next())]++;
    lines++;
}
```

Рекомендуем вам ознакомиться с нашим курсом на сайте [JEasily Course](https://jeasily.com)